# Can't Boot Windows 7 Pro after installing Ubuntu 16

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I've had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16 installed as a dual for some time now running well until I made a stupid move by being curious to see if my new arrived Qubes3.2 would run live from the disc on boot-up.Once I got into system of Qubes I couldn't get out of it, so I shut down the system. Went to reboot again with out Qubes USB into windows 7 or Ubuntu but none were present just Qubes error message, sorry did not write them down. After that I decided to use my Ubuntu 16 USB thought maybe I could restore system so I ran the Boot-Repair " I was unable to see this in the Unetbootin software to download on disc, they may have change the name' so I install via commands. Ran the system this is what the output is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26347924/ Now it did bring back the Ubuntu OS in boot-up but not the Windows 7...Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Link above is for UEFI fixes. But you have BIOS. Have you run `sudo update-grub` ? Also using FAT16 for a 1TB size drive is not recommended. FAT32 is ok for smaller partitions, but FAT does not have journal for chkdsk to fix easily and cannot store files over 4GB. Otherwise you may need to run chkdsk on your NTFS partitions using your Windows repair flash drive.

Comment: I believe I have fixed the issue rebooted and I now see all operating systems thanks to the past post regarding same issue but I see now that there are two Window 7 OS one insda1, and the other in sda2 will this be a problem now, Ubuntu is back at the top?

Comment: Boot-Repair typically copies boot files from sda1 to sda2. Then you can boot from either partition. Many users did not know Windows has a separate Boot partition and houseclean it out. Then have deleted the only way to boot. So Boot-Repair backs up boot files to main (c: drive) partition. And then grub2's os-prober finds both and adds boot entries.